# How to put running book title on the left of even pages?

Tags: books

I am using `artech.cls` (files available https://us.artechhouse.com/Assets/PDFs/textemp.zip)

I need to locate the running book titles on the left part of at even pages. Currently, it locates them in the center. I suspect it is related to the following lines below. What is the best way to solve this issue?

```
\gdef\@booktitle{}
\def\booktitle#1{\gdef\@booktitle{#1}}     
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}\booktitle{#1}}   
\def\ps@headings{%   \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty       \def\@evenhead{\small\thepage\hfill{\small\itshape\rightmark}\hfill\phantom{\thepage}}%
\def\@oddhead{\small\phantom{\thepage}\hfill{\small\itshape\leftmark}\hfill\thepage}%
     \let\@mkboth\markboth \def\chaptermark##1{%   \markboth {{%
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \if@mainmatter
          %
       \fi
     \fi
     ##1}}{}}% \def\sectionmark##1{%   \markleft{\emph{\@booktitle}}}  
      }

 \def\ps@myheadings{%
     \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
     \def\@evenhead{\small\thepage\hfill{\small\itshape\rightmark}\hfill\phantom{\thepage}}%
     \def\@oddhead{\small\phantom{\thepage}\hfill{\small\itshape\leftmark}\hfill\thepage}%
         \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\chaptermark\@gobble
     \let\sectionmark\@gobble
     }

 \pagestyle{headings}
```

Comment: It looks like it also prints the page number at the 'left' of the even-paged headers. What to do about that?

Comment: ? So they are both going to be 'on the left' of even-numbered pages? In what order? What kind of space goes in between? And can you please make an MWE? Otherwise people need to figure out how to use the class (which may be easy or difficult to do) before they can even test a solution. Or look at this line: `\def\@evenhead{\small\thepage\hfill{\small\itshape\rightmark}\hfill\phantom{\thepage}}%`. Seems like the 'culprit' is `\hfill{\small\itshape\rightmark}\hfill`....

Comment: Good point. replacing \hfill with \; worked fine. I will check with the requesters to see if they have a specific space needs.